# Restoring lost LVM VG

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, lvm

I'm trying to restore a Volume Group on a Virtual-Machine that got somehow corrupted.

The lv-root got somehow lost from the VG and the VG showed the originaly allocated space as free.

On the VM we where unable to use the `vgcfgrestore` command.
However we could use it on the host and the VG got restored include all LV's.

Now however when trying to boot the VM "Volume group not found" is shown and wont boot.

`pvs` shows the drive however `vgs` returns `/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket connect failed no such file or directory`

What would be the next step?

`pvscan` shows
[image]

regarding the comments:
[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message about the `lvmetad.socket` is harmless if you are in rescue mode or initramfs; it just means that the lvmetad daemon has not been started yet, and the LVM tools are falling back to reading the LVM metadata by themselves, after complaining about the non-availability of `lvmetad`.  Having said that, **what exactly did you do** with `vgcfgrestore`? If you restored the configuration of the *host's* system VG on the *VM's* disk, it might have appeared correct at first glance but may actually have made the problem worse.

Comment: @telcoM complete command executed on host: vgcfgrestore myUnivativ-vg -f /etc/lvm/backup/myUnivativ-vg result :  Restored volume group myUnivativ-vg - nothing else except some show commands

Comment: OK, that looks good. But what is the relationship between the VG on the host and VG on the VM - are they related at all? Are the devices of the host system presented to the VM as-is, or are the VM's disks actually image files on a filesystem of the host? Do you have any backups of the VM? The contents of the VM's `/etc/lvm` directory could be really helpful.

Comment: @telcoM lvm directory on the vm only contains the lvm.conf. Backups: No, machine wasn't that important. Regarding the other questions I'm sad to say that noone knows. I've attached a screenshot which show the vg's on a gui

Comment: Could you show the disk configuration of the virtual machine, i.e. the `vm.cfg` file or equivalent? If the same physical disk and the same filesystem was simultaneously mounted by both the host and the guest, that would be *a very efficient way to corrupt your filesystem* unless that filesystem is specifically cluster-capable (e.g. GFS or similar) and the appropriate lock manager communication is set up between the host and the guest. So, even if the VM's VG has the same name, *it is most likely not actually the same VG*.

Comment: @telcoM that one: https://pastebin.com/xqtWYjB6 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. It indicates the VM's `/dev/sda` is actually the `/dev/mars_ssd/myUnivativ` on the host. So it's the "myUnivativ" LV in the **"mars_ssd"** VG. That LV has been used as a VM disk image, so it includes a partition table and a LVM layer of its own. So, has something bad happened on the host's `mars_ssd` VG too?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the VM's disk configuration from the pastebin mentioned in the question comments:

```
<devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source dev='/dev/mars_ssd/myUnivativ'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
[...non-disk devices after this point...]
```

The information in the VM configuration indicates the VM disk `/dev/sda` is actually `/dev/mars_ssd/myUnivativ` on the host, i.e. VG `mars_ssd`, LV `myUnivativ`. (Yes, I know the VM configuration says `hda` instead of `sda` - it apparently assumes the VM will be using the old IDE drivers.)

If the `mars_ssd` VG of the host has any problems, you should fix them first at the host level.

Since the `/dev/mars_ssd/myUnivativ` LV contains a VM disk image, it has a partition table and LVM layer of its own.

Since the VM's root filesystem seems to be within the damaged VG, fixing it within the VM will be difficult. You might have an easier time fixing it if you can use all the tools available on the host.

So:

### "Diskception"

- Shutdown the VM.
- Run `sudo losetup -f` on the host to identify the host's first free `/dev/loop*` device. I'll call it `/dev/loopN`.
- Use `sudo losetup /dev/loopN /dev/mars_ssd/myUnivativ` to set up a loop device for the VM's disk. Now you can access the VM's disk image like a regular whole-disk device, even though it's really a LV on the host.
- To gain access to individual partitions on the VM's disk image, use `sudo kpartx -a /dev/loopN`. It will create devices for partitions on the VM's disk image and make them accessible as regular partition devices, named like `/dev/mapper/loopNpP`, where P is the partition number.

Now you can mount any partition on the VM's disk image at the host level: since the VM's PV was indicated as `/dev/sda5` on the host, there will be at least two partitions on the disk image. You can review the partitions with `sudo fdisk -l /dev/loopN`, then mount any interesting partitions like `sudo mount /dev/mapper/loopNp1 /mnt`.

You can even run `pvscan` or `vgscan` and pick up the VM's volume groups at the host level - if their names don't conflict with the host's names. If you find a functional VG, you can activate it with `sudo vgchange -ay` and then mount it as normal.

You can also use any file rescue tools at this point, if you choose to do so.

Before starting the VM again, undo all the things you've done to access the VM's disk image at the host level:

- unmount all the VM's filesystems from the host.
- deactivate all the VM's volume groups from the host with `sudo vgchange -an <name of VM's VG>` if you had them activated
- remove the partition devices with `sudo kpartx -d /dev/loopN`
- disconnect the loop device with `sudo losetup -d /dev/loopN`.

I hope this helps. Please update your question with your findings, and I'll then update my answer if necessary.